# NSTableView: no text in new rows

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, rows

I wrote a method to add new rows to NSTableView. It adds new rows, but there're empty, without text.
Here's code:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{    
    IBOutlet NSButton *addDreamButton;
    IBOutlet NSButton *removeDreamButton;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *dreamField;
    IBOutlet NSTableView *dreamTable;
    IBOutlet NSMutableArray *dreamlist;    
    IBOutlet NSTextField *testf;
}

- (IBAction)addDream:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)deleteDream:(id)sender;

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

-(int) numberOfRowsInTableView: (NSTableView *) tableView
{
    return [dreamlist count];
}

-(void) dreamTable: (NSTableView *) tableview
    setObjectValue:(id)anObject
    objectValueForTableColumn: (NSTableColumn *) tablecolumn
    row:(int) rowIndex
{ 
    [dreamlist replaceObjectAtIndex:rowIndex withObject:anObject];
}

- (IBAction)addDream:(id)sender
{
    NSString* thedream = dreamField.stringValue;
    [dreamlist addObject: thedream];
    [dreamTable reloadData];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
     dreamlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
}
@end
```

AppDelegate is bound as datasource with TableView.

So when I press "add" button empty rows appears in table (textfield where I get text is not empty; I debugged and saw that MutableArray contains right strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table view data source needs to implement this method:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    return [dreamlist objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
}
```